# Shelosha Vachamishim Umatayim - mi yodeya?

Tags: number, mi-yodeya-series

### Who knows two hundred fifty-three?

*Please cite/link your sources, if possible. At some point at least twenty-four hours from now, I will:*

- *Upvote all interesting and relevant answers.*
- *Accept the what I think is the "best" answer.*
- *Move on to the next number.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Weak answer.) There are 253 days before *lag baomer* in a leap year in which *Kislev* has but 29 days.

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/8331 is better (IMO).

Answer (score 4):

There are 22 letters in the Aleph Bais.

1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 + 7 + 8 + 9 + 10 + 11 + 12 + 13 + 14 + 15 + 16 + 17 + 18 + 19 + 20 + 21 + 22 = **253**

Comment: Also producible by n(n+1)/2, in which n = highest number in the series.

Answer (score 3):

והלכתא כוותיה דאביי ביע"ל קג"ם

**253 = יע"ל קג"ם**

Answer (score 3):

Korach + Dasan + Avairam + 250 men = 253 -- Onn Ben Peles dropped out

Answer (score 2):

The word פלשתים appears 253 times in Tanach.

Answer (score 1):

(Very weak answer.) In the year רנ״ג לפ״ק, [Columbus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Origin_theories_of_Christopher_Columbus#Spanish-Jewish_hypothesis) first reached America.