# Arba'a Vachamishim Umatayim - mi yodeya?

Tags: number, mi-yodeya-series

### Who knows two hundred fifty-four?

*Please cite/link your sources, if possible. At some point at least twenty-four hours from now, I will:*

- *Upvote all interesting and relevant answers.*
- *Accept the what I think is the "best" answer.*
- *Move on to the next number.*

[image: Shabbat Shalom!]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

254 men appeared before Moshe during Korach's rebellion:

Korach, Dasan, Aviram, On and 250 prominent men.  (Korach 16:1-2)

וַיִּקַּח קֹרַח, בֶּן-יִצְהָר בֶּן-קְהָת בֶּן-לֵוִי; וְדָתָן וַאֲבִירָם בְּנֵי אֱלִיאָב, וְאוֹן בֶּן-פֶּלֶת--בְּנֵי רְאוּבֵן.  וַיָּקֻמוּ לִפְנֵי מֹשֶׁה, וַאֲנָשִׁים מִבְּנֵי-יִשְׂרָאֵל חֲמִשִּׁים וּמָאתָיִם, נְשִׂיאֵי עֵדָה קְרִאֵי מוֹעֵד, אַנְשֵׁי-שֵׁם

Answer (score 6):

The longest tractate is [Keilim](http://mechon-mamre.org/b/h/h61.htm) which has [254 Mishnayot](http://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%A1%D7%9B%D7%AA_%D7%9B%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%9D#.D7.A4.D7.A8.D7.A7.D7.99_.D7.94.D7.9E.D7.A1.D7.9B.D7.AA).

Answer (score 2):

[According](http://fcit.usf.edu/holocaust/resource/document/DocJager.htm) [to](http://www.shamash.org/holocaust/denial/nazi_doc.txt) [the Jäger Report](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/J%C3%A4ger_Report) (and as [cited](http://books.google.com/books?id=Wb1mg5QWSLEC&pg=PA178&dq=254) by [Martin Gilbert](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martin_Gilbert)), 254 Jewish men were killed by [the Nazis' *Einsatzkommando* 3 and its helpers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rollkommando_Hamann) in [Ukmergė](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ukmerge) on August 1, 1941.

Answer (score 1):

*Lag baomer* is the 254th day of a leap year in which *Kislev* has but 29 days.

Answer (score 0):

254 years after *Yishmael*'s birth, [*Yaakov* "should" have died (at 180)](/q/13047).